# How to update mysql table in PHP on the basis of another table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have the following tables in my database:

Table order

```
|------------------------------------------------------|
| Id    | uid   | order     | price | City_to_be_update
|------------------------------------------------------|
| 1     | 25    | someFoods | 10025 |
|------------------------------------------------------|
| 2     | 30    |Some veggies| 2015|
|------------------------------------------------------|
| 3     | 12    |Milk        | 145 |
|------------------------------------------------------|
```

Table Users:

```
|------------------------------------------------|
| Id    | uid   | city_id   | Address|
|------------------------------------------------|
| 1     | 30    | 1         | myAddress |
|------------------------------------------------|
| 2     | 12    | 2         | Asdfads |
|------------------------------------------------|
| ....  | ..    | ..        | ....... |
|------------------------------------------------|
```

Table City:

```
|------------------------------------------------|
| Id   |city_id| city_name | Country|
|------------------------------------------------|
| 1    | 2     | Abc       | Uae    |
|------------------------------------------------|
| 2    | 3     | Def       | Ghi    |
|------------------------------------------------|
| .... | ..    | ..        | ....... |
|------------------------------------------------|
```

What I want to do is

```
Select * from `order`
    $user_id [ uid ];


Select * from `users` where `uid` = ‘$user_id’;
    $city_id [ city_id ];
```

Select * from `city` where `city_id` = ‘$city_id’;
    $city_name [ city_name ];

Finally want to update the order table as below

```
Update `order` SET ` City_to_be_update`= $city_name’;
```

How to do this, please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Query with Joins,

```
    UPDATE
            < OrderTable > AS a LEFT JOIN < UsersTable > AS b ON a.uid=b.uid
                                LEFT JOIN < CityTable  > AS c ON b.city_id=c.city_id
    SET
            a.City_to_be_update=c.city_name
```